# How should I structure the logic of an object oriented Role-playing game?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Please look at this method in my `player` class of my game:

```
public void eatSomethingt(Items eatable)
{
    foreach (Items i in items)
    {
        if (i is Ieatable && i.name == eatable.name) //Give items an ID in the future
        {
            Ieatable k = i as Ieatable;
            k.eat(this);
            items.Remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this will go through the list of items a player has and compare them to check if the parameter being passed in is eatable, if it is, check if the player have one. If it gets into the IF statement then the item will be removed from the players back-pack(`items`)

The problem is with the line: `k.eat(this)` It is sent to this method:

```
public void eat(Player p)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " Ate the " + name);
    p.life = p.life + amountHealed;
}
```

This feels slightly 'ping-pong'ish as it's the `Fruit` class that feeds the item to the player. As my `Fruit`class implements the interface `iEatable`  (which surely makes sense to do) I have to place an `eat` method in the classes that implement it.

Comment: I think that a player should have the eat method and not the ieatable.

Comment: Umm, no clue about gaming but, shouldn't `eat` be more like: `void eat(IIsFood)`? And randomize in another method if needed of course... `IIsFood` would have like: `int hprestored`, etc...

Comment: Why not introduce a Mouth class that is responsible for eating :-) That way you move out the various responsibilities that would be written inside player (God Object).

Comment: If your code has lots of such constraints, LINQ will be a valuable friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be a method of the player:

And to be more correct `IEatable` should be `IEdible` or even `IConsumable`

```
public class Player
{
    .
    .
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Life {get;set;}
    .
    .
    public void eat(IEdible food)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name + " Ate the " + food.name);
        life += food.amountHealed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Imo eat should be a void in ICanEat interface which player implements... Wouldn't that be more reasonable (i.e. can be used for other mobs, etc.)?

Comment: @StefanDenchev I think you are right, but i just wanted to give a general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Strife for code that looks like a natural language. For example, it does make sense to tell the `Console` to `Write(a)Line`. It makes no sense to tell a food to eat. The food itself should be eaten. Also, food is rarely animated - it doesn't start any interaction with the environment, thus ask yourself whether it should really have any methods? The only thing I come up with now is possibly a `Rot` method, but that can also be implemented in a bacteria class that causes the food to rot. The most OOP way of solving this task seems to be:

1. Food should be a struct with no methods
2. Delegate all the work to the Player

Secondly, why pass a `Items` instance instead of something that is an `IEdible`? Instead, define the method like that:

```
public void eatSomething(IEnumerable<IEdible> eatable)
```

That way any attempt to pass something that can't be eaten are caught at compile time. It also removes the first condition of the `if` statement.

Thirdly, use LINQ to shorten your code.